# Appcelerator Studio 4.5 running error in ubuntu 64

Tags: ubuntu, appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

I'm trying to run `AppceleratorStudio` executable file from Appcelerator_Studio downloaded folder, it will show two error for with `sudo`and without `sudo`. I'm using ubuntu 15.05 x64.

1. sudo ./AppceleratorStudio

   ```
   error: "ooops! you cannot run using sudo. please re-run using NaN account."
   ```
2. ./AppceleratorStudio

   ```
   error: "An error has occurred. See the log file null."
   ```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmV3D.png)

(Build 4.5.0.1446607552) [ERROR]
Ooops! You cannot run using sudo. Please re-run using the NaN account.
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: 
Ooops! You cannot run using sudo. Please re-run using the NaN account.
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.handlers.TitaniumSplashHandler$6.run(TitaniumSplashHandler.java:455)

Comment: could you try and change the permission of the fileTableLock file (as in the error message) so you have user-access? Perhaps the sudo start locked that file.

Comment: what do you mean i have user-access?

Comment: in the error you see "permission denied" which sounds like the file .fileTableLock has no user permission (rwx). So try it with `sudo chmod 777 [path to .fileTableLock]` or even try to delete it and rerun studio

Comment: Appcelerator no longer support Linux for Appcelerator Studio. We still do builds and it might work (since it's "just" Eclipse) but we don't test for it.